# Он или она?

Tags: грамматика

Как сказать о клубе-галерее "Крылатский орнамент" в 3 числе ед.ч. - он или она? Или оно?

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: Он. В случае если у существительного изменяется по падежам только одна часть, род определяется по изменяемой части: персональная ***интернет***-страничка (ж.р.). Если же у существительного изменяются обе части слова, то род определяется по более значимой по смыслу части: вкусный торт-мороженое (м.р.), удобное кресло-кровать (с.р.). Т.е. в соответствии с правилом сказуемое согласуется с той частью сложного наименования, которая выражает более широкое или более конкретное понятие. В вашем случае таким словом является " клуб". Т.е. клуб как галерея, служащий также и галереей.

Answer (score 3):

Всё правильно у Сержа (клуб-галерея – это он), но я попробую обобщить ситуацию.

НЕМНОГО ТЕОРИИ

Если два существительных пишутся через дефис, то между ними может быть чисто сочинительная связь (хлеб-соль, друзья-приятели). Но чаще связь носит больший или меньший оттенок подчинения, и тогда мы имеем  «сущ.+ приложение».

Нормальной позицией для приложения является постпозиция, при этом приложение обычно склоняется: диван-кровать  – диван, который м.б.  кроватью, вагон-ресторан  – вагон, в котором расположен ресторан. Приложение может стоять на первом месте, но при этом словосочетание переходит в сложное слово и приложение не склоняется: интернет-страничка.

РЕШЕНИЕ

Личное местоимение всегда заменяет существительное, но не приложение/определение. Клуб-галерея – "он", потому что клуб – определяемое существительное, а галерея – приложение.